# User Fields on Tooling API

Tags: user, tooling-api

I'm trying to do a query using the Tooling API (using JavaScript) as follows:

```
var query = 'SELECT+Id,+Name+FROM+User+WHERE+Name+LIKE+\'%25' + name + '%25\'';
ftClient.query(query, function(success) { ... }, function(error) { ... } );

...

forceTooling.Client.prototype.query = function(queryString, callback, error) {
    return this.ajax('/' + this.apiVersion + '/tooling/query/?q=' + queryString, callback, error);
};
```

But this query returns the following error:

> SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Name LIKE '%koen%' ^ ERROR at
>   Row:1:Column:12 No such column 'Name' on entity 'User'. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after
>   the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call
>   for the appropriate names.

Now, I'm certain that the "Name" field does exist on the User-object. I also get this error if I try to use the IsActive field. Can anyone explain to me if these fields are not available on the User object through the Tooling API (v28.0) or whether I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the "Name" field on User is not available in Tooling API v28.  I can't confirm, because I can't find the WSDL for v28, but I have seen this error before, and I am pretty sure that is the reason.   Try using higher version of the API.